# Angular add css style dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angular

How to add dynamically css class using angular?

I want to get from backend style properties (i.e `width`, `height`) and create from this properties css style.

So, when in css I would have `class="testClass", "testClass"` should contains properties received from backend.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you need to use `<element style="width: {{widthFromDb }};"` and add those properties there. Or add a `<style>` element in your component that transpile to a variable. something like `<style>.myClass { width: {{widthFromDb }} }</style>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are looking for [ngClass], which works like this:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

Or you could also do:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="getClass()">...</some-element>


getClass() {

 return this.http.get.....
}
```

and return a string. Or You could just assign a variable. It's very flexible to accommodate most situations. But you wouldn't "return properties". What you would do is return a class, which has those properties you want. To set specific properties, I'd recommend using Renderer2:

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

Which has the setStyle method:

```
this.renderer2.setStyle('your element', style: string (such as width), value: any (such as 32px));
```

Comment: But, for [ngClass] I have to have existing css class to assign, and I want to always set the same css class, but properties of class I get from backend.

I.e. from backend I get string "{width: 500px; height: 34px;}" and from this, I want to create "testClass" and for some elements use class="testClass"

Comment: Then Renderer is the route you want to or use javascript/jquery.